# Assign extracted values from aws command to variables in jenkins pipeline

Tags: bash, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, aws-cli

```
def id
def state

pipeline {

agent any

    stages{
        stage('aws') {
            steps {
                script{
                    /*extract load generator instanceId*/
                    sh "aws ec2 describe-instances --filters 'Name=tag:Name,Values=xxx' --output text --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].{id:InstanceId,state:State.Name}' --region us-east-1"
                    echo "id and state: ${id} ${state}"  
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to extract the `instace id` and `state` of the `xxx` instance using the above command and able to get the values of them
But when I try to `echo` them I get the values as `null`. So they are not being assigned to the `${id}` and `{state}` variables
Is there any way I could assign them to the above variables in `jenkins pipeline`
Note: Don't want to use `jq`
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your current implementation doesn't assign any variables, shell, Jenkins, or otherwise. `id` and `instanceState` are just aliases for other fields in the context of the aws command. In order to have access to those values in the context of the pipeline, I'd recommend combining the output of the `sh` step with the `readJSON` step (it's part of the [pipeline utility steps plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-utility-steps-plugin/blob/master/docs/STEPS.md)). Then you can do something like this:

```groovy
def id
def state

pipeline {

    agent any

    stages{
        stage('aws') {
            steps {
                script{
                    /*extract load generator instanceId*/
                    instanceInfo = sh (
                            script: "aws ec2 describe-instances --filters 'Name=tag:Name,Values=xxx' --output text --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].{id:InstanceId,instanceState:State.Name}' --region us-east-1",
                            returnStdout: true
                    ).trim()
                    instanceJSON = readJSON text: instanceInfo
                    instanceJSON.each { instance ->
                        echo "${instance.id[0]}: ${instance.instanceState[0]}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(I hand-fudged a couple of those items for my minimal test case; please post any errors you get and we'll clean things up)